# nginx unwanted location redirect with trailing slash

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxypass

I have a location

```
location /pass/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:12345/;
}
```

So it is supposed to proxify urls `http://example.com/pass/whatever` to `http://localhost:12345/whatever`

The thing I don't like about it is that nginx is automatically adding slash to

```
http://example.com/pass
```

and makes it `http://example.com/pass/` via 301 redirect

How can I simply avoid this behavior. I want `/pass` without trailing slash to go to another location. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solved it with regex (`/pass/(.*)`...`/$1$is_args$args`), other solutions would be appreciated

Comment: Just in case it helps others finding themselves here questioning 301 redirects coming from their nginx-proxied webapps, make sure it's not the webapp doing it.  That was the cause in my case, not nginx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop nginx 301 auto redirect when trailing slash is not in URI?](http://serverfault.com/questions/759762/how-to-stop-nginx-301-auto-redirect-when-trailing-slash-is-not-in-uri)

Answer (score 6):

There's a special case where a `proxy_pass` with a `location` ending in `/` would result in an automatic implicit `301` redirect without going to the backend; you have to create an explicit `location` without the trailing slash to avoid this:

- http://nginx.org/r/location

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, or grpc_pass, then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI and location could be defined like this:
>
> ```
> location /user/ {
>     proxy_pass http://user.example.com;
> }
>
> location = /user {
>     proxy_pass http://login.example.com;
> }
> ```

E.g., you gotta create an explicit `/pass` `location` in addition to the existing `/pass/` one, otherwise, an implicit `location /pass {return 301 /pass/…;}` will be created for you.

However, are you sure you actually want to do what you're trying to do?  If you're going to omit a redirect from `/pass` to `/pass/`, then relative paths aren't going to work.  Some newer browsers also have a tendency to feature defective UI/UX that may not present the trailing slash to the user, which may make things even more confusing when trying to troubleshoot the distinction.

Comment: the point is that location `/pass/` is forcing redirect for `/pass` to match it as long as I think, `/pass` should better match location `/` and not `/pass/`

Comment: @cnst: actually it will, and it's documented as doing that. See the last paragraph of http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location . What's going on is that if you include any of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, or memcached_pass in a location with a trailing slash, it sets the 'auto_redirect' flag on the location, which triggers the redirect on this line: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/1176952193ccf47078dc84b8494d0496ad1ac4a2/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L1684

Answer (score 2):

As you want it to go to **another location**, a natural solution is to add that location

```
location /pass {
}
```

By default, nginx will look for a file called 'pass' in the web root. If you don't like this default, you may add more directives inside this new location block to achieve that.

You may also use

```
location = /pass {
}
```

such that nginx can find the match a bit faster.

Comment: Yeas, this is solution, but It can bloat config in some cases ;(